# Find items from List based on matching property

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a Groovy class:

```
class GlobalUsers {

    String name = ""
    String ID = ""
    ................
    ................
}
```

Now in another function:

```
List<GlobalUsers> guObjs = new List<GlobalUsers>();
```

Here I have few hundreds of objects of GlobalUsers in a List.

I want to find all objects of GlobalUsers where string name == "User_CUSTOM"

So basically the result will be another List:

```
List<GlobalUsers> guObjs = *name == "User_CUSTOM"*
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`findAll()`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html#findAll(groovy.lang.Closure)) method:

```
def globalUsers = guObjs.findAll { it.name == "User_CUSTOM" }
```